# Installing Golang Oracle but getting "error: undefined reference to 'golang.org_x_tools_container_intsets.popcount'"

Tags: go

I tried installing Oracle on my Ubuntu machine using the following cmd:

> go get golang.org/x/tools/cmd/oracle

but I am getting the following error:

> #golang.org/x/tools/cmd/oracle
>   /home/rr/Proj/go/src/golang.org/x/tools/container/intsets/sparse.go:140: error: undefined reference to 'golang.org_x_tools_container_intsets.popcount'
>   /home/rr/Proj/go/src/golang.org/x/tools/container/intsets/util.go:51: error: undefined reference to 'golang.org_x_tools_container_intsets.popcount'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

My Go version is

> go version xgcc (Ubuntu 4.9.1-0ubuntu1) 4.9.1 linux/amd64

Anyone else facing the same issue?

Comment: Make sure your checkout is up to date by using the `-u` option with `go get`. I would also install an up to date version of the official version of go (it's possible that gccgo may not work with Oracle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like we need to remove gcc-go(installed using apt-get) and install Go from the website https://golang.org/ . This fixes the issue.